# why is the install procedure for gtk+ so complicated?

Tags: gtk, glib, pango

I am trying to install gtk+ (3.20.3) on ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded the gtk + package & ran the configure command. I got

```
Requested 'atk >= 2.15.1' but version of Atk is 2.10.0

Requested 'pango >= 1.37.3' but version of Pango is 1.36.3

Requested 'cairo >= 1.14.0' but version of cairo is 1.13.1

Requested 'cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0' but version of cairo-gobject is 1.13.1
```

I also got the above version mismatch error for glib which I installed & after installing some other pre-requisites it asked for.

I am now recursively stuck in installing each one of the above, each asks something else. For ATK I get some error like "../atk/.libs/libatk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a'", whcih I have to try and solve.

The question why is it so complicated ? AM I doing something wrong? Is there no step like  "apt-get install gtk" or something like that. I have spent more than 2 hours and nowhere near completion.

I just wanted gtk+ installed as I needed a simple UI for a certain C program. I did not realize installation will be so difficult.

Comment: Use jhbuild. It will make all that dependency nonsense easier, and will install GTK+ in a private namespace so it doesn't interfere with the rest of your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure for build GTK+ from source is not any more complicated than the procedure for building other projects. GTK+ has various dependencies, instead of bundling everything into its own repositories; this means that you need to check the list of dependencies (as specified inside the `configure.ac` file) and install or build them.

If you want to set up a development environment the suggestion is to use jhbuild, which is similar to `virtualenv` for Python. The `jhbuild` command knows all the dependencies needed to build various projects in the GNOME platform, including GTK+, and will download, build, and install those dependencies in a separate prefix, allowing you to build your own code in that prefix as well.

You can get quickly started with jhbuild by reading the [GNOME Newcomers guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers).

Comment: I needed to use the GTK+ library to build UI onto a C application. I went the path of downloading the GTK+ code & building and got into a loop. I now have a env where I have most of GTK+ code downloaded and built but not the pango piece (not able to resolve dependencies there). I will try jhbuild. I have also tried to install the libgtk-2-dev libraries & later libgtk-3-dev also. I think I now have quite a messed up environment now as some sample programs that I got with GTK+ are giving some functions as unresolved.  Accepting this answer as 'why is it complicated?' was answered :-)

Comment: The Newcomers link has a typo. It should be https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers. A missing 'r' in the link

Answer (score 5):

@ebassi is correct assuming you need a newer version of GTK+, or want to develop GTK+ itself. If all you want is to write a GTK application, and aren't picky about the version, check out the Ubuntu package `libgtk-3-dev`.

Comment: My env is a bit messed up as mentioned in my comment to @ebassi.  Your suggestion here should help me get my C code to built I think. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the total documentation hell for GTK makes it necessary to read the source, single step debug it and add printf to the core libraries to understand whats going on and so everyone seriously developing with GTK will soon or later need his/her own libraries.  And it would be better if the C files could be added to your IDE to get full source code browing, but without a move to cmake there is no way for this at the moment.